# Conditional distribution of life time for a renewal process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> Assume $\{X_i:i=1,2,\ldots\}$ are independent random variables with probability distribution $f(x)$, associated with a renewal process. If we know the number of renewals at time $t$ is $n$, find the join probability distribution of $X_i$s when $t\to \infty$.

**Solution:** First, we should find 
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X_1\leq x_1, \ldots, X_n\leq x_n \Bigg| N(t)=n\right) =\mathbb{P}\left(X_1\leq x_1, \ldots, X_n\leq x_n \Bigg| \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k \leq t < \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}X_k\right) = \frac{\mathbb{P}\left(X_1\leq x_1, \ldots, X_n\leq x_n \bigcap \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k \leq t < \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}X_k\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k \leq t < \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}X_k\right)}$$

I have no idea how to continue from here. I think this should have been addressed in the literature. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: This does not converge to anything that looks like a distribution when $t \rightarrow \infty$. For example, in the special case when the random variables are i.i.d. exponential, they form a Poisson process and conditioning on $N(t)=n$ means the $n$ times are independently and uniformly distributed over $[0,t]$, but letting $t\rightarrow\infty$ means the interval size gets larger and larger and the probability all spacings are less than any given $\theta>0$ goes to zero as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @michael I see your point. But, let's assume $n,t$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Note also that the problem does not even make sense in other cases, like when $X_i \in [0,1]$ for all $i$, then conditinoing on $N(t)=n$ conditions on an impossible event when $t>n+1$.